# Javascript confirm error

Tags: javascript, html

I want a confirm box to pop up when someone tries to submit this delete form. It does, but regardless of whether you click "OK" or "cancel" it submits the form and deletes the data. Here's the html:

```
<input type='submit' onclick='delete_note_alert()' name='delete' value='Delete'></form>
```

and here's the javascript

```
function delete_note_alert()
{
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this note?");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `return` statement to both the `delete_note_alert` function and the `onclick` attribute. An even will be cancelled upon returning `false`.

```
<input type='submit' onclick='return delete_note_alert()' name='delete' value='Delete'>

function delete_note_alert()
{
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this note?");
}
```

Comment: Or you could leave it as is, and let the outer `form` tag in the posted markup submit when the user clicks OK, which could delete the record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onsubmit() event in your form

```
<form name="my_name" action="my_action.php" onsubmit="delete_note_alert()">
   ....  
   ....
   <input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'>
</form>
```

You can change your function like so:

```
function delete_note_alert()
{
    var c = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this note?");
    /* Do nothing with the variable. Proceed with the code to delete, irrespective of value of variable c is true or false */
    /* Your delete code */
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your just missing a conditional.

```
function delete_note_alert(e)
{
    /*If the user doesn't want to delete the post*/
    if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this note?"))
       /*Stop default action (form submit)*/
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do as below.

```
function delecte_alert() { 
    var result = confirm("are you sure?");
    if (result) {
         // do something when OK clicked
    }
    else {
        // do something when cancel clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this too

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit='return delete_note_alert()'>

<input type='submit'  name='delete' value='Delete'>

function delete_note_alert()
{
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this note?");
}
```

Hope this helps